# ice:paneConfirmation - is it really so bad?

Tags: icefaces

I have discovered a nice component for confirming actions - ice:panelConfirmation. But I think, it has one big mistake. I can't change the name of heading, there is always "Confirm". It is really so bad? Or is there some possibility to change it? I need to translate it to another language, for example.

Here is my code:

```
 <ice:panelConfirmation id="deleteConfirm" message="#{msg['really']}" 
                                       acceptLabel="#{msg['yes']}" styleClass="dialog" 
                                       cancelLabel="#{msg['no']}" displayAtMouse="true"/>
```

...

```
  <ice:commandButton image="/resources/images/delete.png" action="#{postManager.delete(item)}" 
                                         title="#{msg['news.delete']}" styleClass="smallSpaces"
                                         panelConfirmation="deleteConfirm"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ice:panelConfirmation component has a "title" attribute that you can use to set the text of the popup header. Have a look [here](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/compat/comps/tld/)

Comment: Thanks, Razvan. I tried it, but it had still show "Confirm". Now it works fine. I had to be bad deployment.